# Why can't I insert title in wx.panel plot?

Tags: python, plot, wxpython

I have built a GUI with two panels, one for one button and the other for plot some data. In the latter panel I used a Class wx.Panel and call it inside the Frame. Now I'm trying to change the title of the plot when I press the button inside the Frame but I'm getting this error **AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasWxAgg' object has no attribute 'axes'** and I don't know how to solve it. This is the code that I'm using (I will post just the button and the panel code):

```
    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def m_button1OnButtonClick( self, event ):
        self.m_globalupperpanel.figure.canvas.axes.set_title("Degrees")


###########################################################################
## Class Plot Panel
###########################################################################

class Plot_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()

        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
```

Thank you for your help.
Kind Regards
Ivo

Comment: `axes` is an attribute of a `Plot_Panel` instance, not the `self.m_globalupperpanel.figure.canvas` instance of the `FigureCanvasWxAgg` class.

Comment: Sorry but I miss your annswer at first. With your explanation I understood the problem and figured out the solution. Thank your for your help. Kind Regards.Ivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.axes.set_title("title") should work. What were you using to set the title?

Comment: At first I draw the plot without title and later I will want to add title, xlabel, ylabel and even redraw the plot with new values when I press one button, but I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Instead self.axes.set_title("title") I used  self.m_globalupperpanel.axes.set_title("Title") since the plot is inside a panel called m_globalupperpanel. Thank you for your help. Kind Regards. Ivo

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.